# How do I get a custom Jekyll permalink style scoped to just some posts (ie blog posts)?

Tags: configuration, jekyll

I'd like blog posts on my Jekyll site to follow a specific URL convention. I'd like to avoid having permalinks even in the frontmatter. I'd prefer to specify my style in one place and never have to think about it again.

In `_config.yaml` you can specify a custom [permalink style](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) as follows:

```
permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/
```

And posts will have a default permalink that looks something like /blog/2015/01/24/some-title/ (assuming 01-24-2015 publish date).

However, I'd like to scope this only to our blog directory. So I tried to use defaults in `_config.yaml' as [specified](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) in the Jekyll docs

```
defaults:
    -
        scope:
            path: "blog"
            type: "posts"
        values:
            permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:title/
```

Unfortunately, the permalink for my test post is literally `http://localhost:4000/blog/:year/:month/:title`

Why don't defaults behave the same way as the root permalink? Is there another way to accomplish what I want?

I'm hoping to do this without a custom plugin, as we're using GH pages and plugin options are limitted.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with version 2.4.0. i upgraded using

```
gem update jekyll
```

and it updated to 2.5.3. fixed my issue.